# Add Margin But Keep Row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add spacing between elements, but in doing so, my last img moves to the next column. How do I auto resize them so they all stay in the same row?

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbsWrapper">
  <div><img class="column" src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div><img class="column" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div><img class="column" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-247932.jpeg" alt="codepen"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use a flexbox model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The problem is in your `padding` as padding is **added** to the width, so they really aren't `33.333%` but rather `33.333% + 6px`.

To fix this you need to change the `box-sizing` property to `border-box`. This takes the padding into consideration when calculating the width of the element.

The first way, is I moved the padding off of the image and moved it to it's container. This is a personal preference as adding padding to `img` elements seems weird to me.

The second way is how you have it, just adding the `box-sizing: border-box` property to the `img.column` class.

```css
div.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

div.column img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Original Way */
img.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbsWrapper">
  <div class="column"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div class="column"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div class="column"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="codepen"></div>
</div>


<!-- Original Way -->
<div id="thumbsWrapper">
  <div><img class="column" src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div><img class="column" src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div><img class="column" src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="codepen"></div>
</div>
```

You can use `flexbox` as the comment points out, but it might be overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With Flexbox, here is the example.
You can give padding in the `.inner` class.

```css
#thumbsWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbsWrapper">
  <div class="inner"><img class="column" src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div class="inner"><img class="column" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="codepen"></div>
  <div class="inner"><img class="column" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-247932.jpeg" alt="codepen"></div>
</div>
```